# Calling a c# method when changing TextBoxes values without any click button

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

I want to call a c# method "test()" that loads data from database. That call should be in every change of my TextBoxes values..I have two TextBoxes and when I write something there a gridview should be appeared (that's what test() should do)..I am using jQuery to call test() in every changement of TextBoxes without using any button but that couldn't run..I appreciate any help :)

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".calculate").each(function() {
            $(this).keyup(function() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "FirstPage.aspx/test",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(response) {
                        $("#Content").text(response.d);
                    },
                    failure: function(response) {
                        alert(response.d);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

The TextBoxes:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Width="140px" Height="16px" CssClass="calculate" ></asp:TextBox>

<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Width="140px" Height="16px" CssClass="calculate" ></asp:TextBox>
```

Test():

```
 protected  void test(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     load();
   }


   protected string load()
  {

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=ic-webdev;Initial Catalog=intracall;User ID=sa;Password=xs4intracall";
        con.Open();

        SqlDataAdapter ada = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT COUNT(*) as Count where Firstname='"+TextBox1+"' and Lastname='"+TextBox2+"' FROM contact", con);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        ada.Fill(dt);
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();

        con.Close();

 }
```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.textchanged(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Does the test() run ? ( if you put a breakpoint )

Comment: @ParkashKumar  last time I used that it caused a postback on every key press. Has something changed?

Comment: It will, because on every key press it will call listener.

Comment: @nAviD you describe your goals and your attempt very well. But you do not describe the failure at all. If we don't know what the problem is we can't help you.

Comment: @ParkashKumar  right. Exactly what the OP is trying to avoid by using Ajax.

Comment: @SamAxe Do you really mean me ?

Comment: yes the test() runs correctly..and the postback didn't change anything

Comment: Can you provide the test function too ?

Comment: the problem that when I write something in the tetxBox, nothing happens

Comment: the test() function is provided

Comment: does your code even compile?

Comment: @nAviD: no, sorry, I meant Manou.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("input").keyup(function () {
        alert("dsfd");
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "FirstPage.aspx/test",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                $("#Content").text(response.d);
            },
            failure: function (response) {
                alert(response.d);
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: It doesn't run my function test()..it shows me only the alert window